# How to fix java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)) error

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc, permissions

I've looked at all the questions asked about this and can't seem to get mine to work. I'm running a web application on eclipse while using a mysql database. I have no errors apart from the context.xml when I try to run I get the error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

This is what my context.xml looks like:

```
<Context>

  <Resource name="jdbc/HenryBooksWebApp1" 
            auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
               username="root" password="root" 
               driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/henrybooks?useSSL=false"/>

</Context>
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: have you granted privileges to root user for henrybooks database?

Comment: Are you able to connect the database from any db client application?

Comment: @satya how do I do that exactly?

Comment: @SundaraBalajiJK im not sure what you mean by that exactly

Comment: @AbdulBalogun login into mysql from command line and then issue the command GRANT ALL ON henrybooks.* TO 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: @Satya just tried that and it didnt work although ive never used the command line, is there no way to fix it purely by editing the context.xml file?

Comment: Unless you login into DB , I guess not

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced the same issue:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
```

**The reason:** there was no match between the settings of **properties** file and **context.xml** in my case.

For example, if **properties** file looks like:

```
DATABASE_DRIVER_NAME=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF8
DATABASE_USER=root
DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
```

**context.xml** can be with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context path="/CarRental">
    <Resource name="jdbc/appname"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100" 
              maxIdle="30"
              maxWait="10000"
              username="root"
              password="root"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8"/>
</Context>
```

As a result, there will be a complete correspondence between files and application will work correctly without error.